# How can I remove the current year in my developer name in the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios11

I released an iOS app in the App Store, but my developer name displays as **"2017 [developer name]"**. I need only the developer name to show, without the **"2017"**.Please check attached screenchot.

[Screenshot image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vci3Z.jpg)

Comment: The developer name can not be changed, once set that is it.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes
But i had not set developer name with "2017" at any place

Comment: The fist time you submit an app iTunesConnect ask for the Developers name. Once set you can not change it. Thus some one has entered it. Unless you are talking about the copyright, this you can change by submitting a new version of the app and changing it on iTunesConnect.

Comment: But After login in "itunesconnect". i am not find "2017" at any place. And "itunesconnect" display only developer name not with 2017.

Comment: Can you post a screen shots of what you want to change, this might make it more clear.

Comment: @rckoenes I have add screenshot please check

Comment: Well that is the developers name and can not be changed. You might want to contact Apple if they can change it, but I've never had any luck with that

Comment: Thanks buddy. I agree with you.
But i did not set this type of name any place when i create app in ituneconnects. that's why i have ask this question.
I will try to contact apple for this.

Comment: We you create your very first app in your account it will ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are referring to the **copyright details** of your application.

You can change the copyright details in iTunes Connect under **My Apps/App Store/iOS App/[app version]/General App Information/Copyright**. The changes will show up in the App Store after releasing a new version.

[image: Copyright in iTunes Connect]

Comment: Thanks @the4kman 
I had change this copyright detail and release new version of app but it not effect to developer text. Developer text is same as old

Comment: Like I said, you cannot change the developers name.